# C# Unity3D Scale using Accelerometer with Clamp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, accelerometer, clamp

I'm trying to translate the roll(y) of a phone into the scale of an object but with size limits.

I have had success scaling to infinity +- with the following code:

```
void Update () {
   float accelY = Input.acceleration.y;
   transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, accelY, 0);
}
```

The problem I am having is with the max and min limits of the scale.

I attempted to use Clamp in the following way but have ended up just limiting the direction of scale where -y (rolling toward myself) equals 0 therefore no shrinking happens and +y (rolling away from self) scales up endlessly assumed at a max rate of 0.045f.

```
transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(accelY, 0f, 0.045f), 0);
```

In an ideal world I'd like to have a min scale of y = 1 and a max scale y = 100 and as you roll the phone back and forth it would tween between the two sizes.

I can find code snippets for Translate and rotate but nothing for scaling.. Please help.

Comment: Ok. You want the scale of the model to be btw 1 and 100. What about the acceleration value? What's the min and max of that? You can check with Debug.Log to figure out this.

Comment: I'm not sure, the range I get is from debug.log is -10 to +10.

well I guess it's more relative to rotation of the phone, if the phone is flat on it's back then I expect the y scale to be 1 and if the phones back is facing outward (-90°) then I expect the y scale of zero. 

If I can explain the project a bit more. I have some terrain that I would like to be flat when looking at it from side on (like a paper map), then when the user moves the phone into a top down position it raises the terrain to a scale of 1 (full height). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Update () {
   float accelY = Input.acceleration.y;
   transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.y + accelY, 1f, 
   100f), 0)
}
```

You should add Time.deltaTime because Update is frames/sec dependant:

```
[SerializeField]
float speed = 10f;
[SerializeField]
float minSize = 1f;
[SerializeField]
float maxSize = 100f;

void Update () {
   float accelY = Input.acceleration.y * Time.deltaTime * speed;
   transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.localScale.y + accelY, minSize , 
   maxSize ), 0)
}
```

Comment: Spot on @kamyker It does exactly what I wanted it to, I really appreciate the help!

For others reference, I modified X & Z vectors to 1 instead of 0, my mistake on the original code, so now the model is correct in width and depth it's just height that is being affected.

My final values after testing were
float speed = 50f;
float minSize = 0.01f;
float maxSize = 2f;

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you want to scale value from one range(accelerometer) to another 0 - 100. If that's the case then this is not best done with the clamp function. You can do it with the [map](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/map) function:

```
float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```

Pass the accelerometer value (`Input.acceleration.y`) as the main value. The `inValueMin` value should the minimum accelerometer value you prefer. The `inValueMax` value should the the maximum accelerometer value you prefer. This is totally up to you to decide.

The `outValueMin` and `outValueMax` values are the is range of the output. In your case, that's `0` and `100`.

Something like below should get you started:

```
//Scale Min and max
public float scaleMin = 0;
public float scaleMax = 100f;

//Accelerometer min/max. Find this with Debug.Log(Input.acceleration.y);
public float accelYMin = -10;
public float accelYMax = 10;

void Update()
{
    float accelY = Input.acceleration.y;
    float scaledVal = mapValue(accelY, accelYMin, accelYMax, scaleMin, scaleMax);
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, scaledVal, 0);
}

float mapValue(float mainValue, float inValueMin, float inValueMax, float outValueMin, float outValueMax)
{
    return (mainValue - inValueMin) * (outValueMax - outValueMin) / (inValueMax - inValueMin) + outValueMin;
}
```